# cakePHP: How to change the ID of a form element (using the form helper)?

Tags: php, cakephp, formhelper

I've created a form which has a loop to display a number of rows. I have a select on each row using the form helper. The IDs it creates are all the same, is there a way to add a counter, or some defining info to the ID?

I'm using `$this->Form->input('city_id')` to output a select of the cities from my city model.  All the IDs are `ModelCityId`. I'd like to get something like ModelCityId1, `ModelCityId2`, `ModelCityId3`, etc.  Is this possible? Or is there a better way to go about displaying options in a loop?

Thanks for any suggestions you might have.

Here is the relevant part of the code.

```
while ($current_date != $departure_date) {
  $current_date = date("d-M-y", strtotime($current_date . " +1 day"));
  $output .= '<tr>';
  $output .= '<td>'.$current_date.'</td>';
  // irrelevant other columns
  $output .= '<td>'.$this->Form->input('city_id', array('label' => '', 'empty' => true)).'</td>';
  $output .= '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: `$current_date = date("d-M-y", strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($current_date)) . " +1 day"));`
 this line baffles me.

Comment: There might be a better way to do it, but I'm using that to add a day to a date string (coming in from another section of the site, already formatted).
-- Had a closer look and realized I was over complicating it a bit. Changed to `$current_date = date("d-M-y", strtotime($current_date . " +1 day"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ids are the same, the name is the same as well. That'll mess up your data when you submit it. You're looking for this syntax:

```
$this->Form->input("ModelName.$i.city_id", array(...))
```

Use the `ModelName` that you're making the form for (i.e. the same as in `$this->Form->create('ModelName')`).

Answer (score 3):

As itchy points out, simply use a counter in your `while` loop to get a unique number.

Then all you have to do is assign it to your ID field

```
$this->Form->input('city_id', array('id' => 'somvalue' . $i));
```

Assuming `$i` is defined in your loop.

Comment: I didn't see ID as an option I could set when I was looking through the cake docs, so I didn't even think to try that. It worked, thanks guys.

Comment: Cake only lists the additional options you can set (e.g. - default, after, before). However, in addition to those all html options like class, id, name can be set in that options array as well.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: why can't you do something like this:

```
$counter = 0;
while ($current_date != $departure_date) {
  $current_date = date("d-M-y", strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($current_date)) . " +1 day"));
  $output .= '<tr>';
  $output .= '<td>'.$current_date.'</td>';
  // irrelevant other columns
  $output .= '<td>'.$this->Form->input('city_id' . $counter, array('label' => '', 'empty' => true)).'</td>';
  $output .= '</tr>';
  $counter++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thought @ithcy. I've added the code to my original post. I think the change will have to be made through an option of the input function, I'm just not sure what to look for.

Comment: See my edit. It may not conform to CakePHP's field naming conventions for model binding or whatever, but I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Comment: ah... I see now. I don't know CakePHP that well. I will try to come up with a better answer.